# Promise: how to pass function with parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

In the following test code, I try to pass predefined function with parameters (i.e., t2, t3) to then. But it complains "r" not defined.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var t2 = function(r) {
    console.log("2r: " + r);
    return 2 * r;
};

var t3 = function(r) {
    console.log("3r: " + r);
    return 3 * r;
};

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(1);
        reject(2)
    }, 1000);
})
.then(t2(r), t3(r))
.then(t2(r), t3(r))
.then(t2(r), t3(r));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the function names instead:

```js
var t2 = function(r) {
  console.log("2r: " + r);
  return 2 * r;
};

var t3 = function(r) {
  console.log("3r: " + r);
  return 3 * r;
};

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(1);
      reject(2)
    }, 1000); // (*)

  })
  .then(t2, t3)
  .then(t2, t3)
  .then(t2, t3);
```

If you *actually* want to pass additional parameters *that you know beforehand*, make `t2` and `t3` *higher-order* functions that *return* functions, so that you can invoke inside a `.then`'s parameter list:

```js
var t2 = extra => r => {
  console.log("2r: " + r);
  console.log('extra param: ' + extra);
  return 2 * r;
};

var t3 = extra => r => {
  console.log("3r: " + r);
  console.log('extra param: ' + extra);
  return 3 * r;
};


const r = 'foo';
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(1);
      reject(2)
    }, 1000); // (*)

  })
  .then(t2(r), t3(r))
  .then(t2(r), t3(r))
  .then(t2(r), t3(r));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing `r` to the functions. `.then` passes a value to a callback.

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    resolve(1)
    reject(2)
  })
})
.then((r) => /* do stuff with r here */)
```

If you need to log out the results, you'd have something like `.then((r) => { t2(r); t3(r); })`. If you just need to return the result of the multiplication function (or whatever), `.then(t2)` would work (for one function). Note that I'm using arrow functions here; they work in Node and most browsers now, but you could use the `function` keyword instead if you wanted.

You're also using the comma operator strangely here -- remember, it's basically the same as having a statement and *then* a return, and since your functions don't perform any mutation (just the `log` side effect), you're not actually going to affect any data with the first function in each `.then`.